# How to pass pointer to pointer parameters when using pinvoke?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, dllimport

There is a C code. I want to wrap it in C# with PInvoke.

```
struct Item {
    int color;
    int shape;
};

UINT8 get_item(struct Item** i) {
    *i = (struct Item*) malloc(sizeof(struct Item));
    if(*i != NULL) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

and the C# code as following

```
[DllImport("sample.dll", EntryPoint = "get_item")]
public static extern Byte get_item(out IntPtr ptr);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IntPtr new_item_ptr;
    get_item(out new_item_ptr);
    IntPtr oneDeep = (IntPtr)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new_item_ptr, typeof(IntPtr));
    Item out_item = (Item )Marshal.PtrToStructure(oneDeep, typeof(Item));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I found the value of out_item was wrong.
How should I fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

This line should use `new_item_ptr`, not `dev`

```
IntPtr oneDeep = (IntPtr)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new_item_ptr, typeof(IntPtr));
```